# Check Series string containing list of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to perform the following:

for each row, check if the df['Text'] matching any string in every row in df1['Criteria'], matching even one of them will result in true.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Test excel.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('Sorting Critiria.csv')
df['Match'] = df['Text'].str.contains(df1['Criteria 1'])

#seems like only 'actual' string can be put inside str.contains()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` by `|` for regex `or`:

```
df['Match'] = df['Text'].str.contains('|'.join(df1['Criteria 1']))
```